# Matlab Backgroundcolourplot

Tags: matlab, plot

I have got a polarplot with 3 "circles" and want to change the color between the first and third circle to grey. My code is:
"polarplot(Ext);
grid on"

Can anyone help me

Comment: Can you add the image that is generated? or some code that can be run to generate it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.